# Condition always evaluates to else branch

Tags: python

When I type `play`, a random number is assigned to `number1`. It asks me for a prediction and I put in a number, say 5. After putting in 5 I always get the `else` statement and not the `if` statement. I even put a `print()` to find out what number was generated. Sometimes I'm right on or within 1 (The game also allows for within 1) and it still re-directs me to the `else` statement. Could anyone help? Thanks.

```
money = 1000000

def luckyrollgame():
    global money
    from random import choice
    print('You are in the game lobby of Lucky Roll.')
    print('Choose either \'rules,\' \'play,\' or \'back\'')
    lobby = input()
    if lobby == 'rules':
        luckyrollgamerules()
    if lobby == 'play':
        die = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        number1 = choice(die)
        prediction = input('Please type your prediction number: ')
        if prediction == number1:
            print('Good job! You guessed right!')
            money = money + 3
            print('You now have ' + str(dollars) + 'dollars.')
        if prediction == number1 - 1:
            print('Good job! You guessed right!')
            money = money + 3
            print('You now have ' + str(dollars) + 'dollars.')
        if prediction == number1 + 1:
            print('Good job! You guessed right!')
            money = money + 3
            print('You now have ' + str(dollars) + 'dollars.')
        else:
            print('I\'m sorry. You didn\'t get the number right.')
            print('The number was ' + str(number1) + '.')
            money = money - 1
            print('You now have ' + str(money) + 'dollars.')
            print('--------------------------------------------------')
            altluckyrollgame()
    if lobby == 'back':
        altvillagescene()
    else:
        print('Please type a valid option.')
        print('--------------------------------')
        altluckyrollgame()
```

*Functions such as `altluckyrollgame()` or `altvillagescene()` are part of the game logic and defined elsewhere, so you can ignore them.

Comment: Do consider more descriptive titles for your questions in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `elif` statement after the very first statement. At current, your code

```
    if lobby == 'back':
        altvillagescene()
    else:
        print('Please type a valid option.')
        print('--------------------------------')
        altluckyrollgame()
```

is checking if lobby == 'back' and running the else in all other cases. You probably don't want this, as the code under else is run in addition to every other if case.

```
if x == 0: pass
elif x == 1: pass
else: pass
```

Code should look like this

```
money = 1000000

def luckyrollgame():
    global money
    from random import choice
    print('You are in the game lobby of Lucky Roll.')
    print('Choose either \'rules,\' \'play,\' or \'back\'')
    lobby = input()
    if lobby == 'rules':
        luckyrollgamerules()
    elif lobby == 'play':
        die = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        number1 = choice(die)
        prediction = input('Please type your prediction number: ')
######################### This too
        try: prediction = int(prediction)
        except ValueError: prediction = -10
#########################
        if prediction == number1:
            print('Good job! You guessed right!')
            money = money + 3
            print('You now have ' + str(dollars) + 'dollars.')
        elif prediction == number1 - 1:
            print('Good job! You guessed right!')
            money = money + 3
            print('You now have ' + str(dollars) + 'dollars.')
        elif prediction == number1 + 1:
            print('Good job! You guessed right!')
            money = money + 3
            print('You now have ' + str(dollars) + 'dollars.')
        else:
            print('I\'m sorry. You didn\'t get the number right.')
            print('The number was ' + str(number1) + '.')
            money = money - 1
            print('You now have ' + str(money) + 'dollars.')
            print('--------------------------------------------------')
            altluckyrollgame()
    elif lobby == 'back':
        altvillagescene()
    else:
        print('Please type a valid option.')
        print('--------------------------------')
        altluckyrollgame()
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! I can only accept your answer in 4 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're comparing a string to an integer.

You'll need to first convert the input to an `int`:

```
try:
    guess = int(prediction)
except ValueError:
    #Handle when a person enters an invalid number here
```

Comment: Also, the structure should be `if-elif`, not seperate `if` statements. :)

Comment: @ Sukrit Kalra Yes. I'm accepting Travis GD's answer which had both the elif statements and the prediction = int(prediction)

Answer (score 0):

The `prediction` returned by `input()` is a **string**, so all the comparisons fail. Try casting the value to an integer:

```
prediction = int(input())
```

Comment: Welp, the typos caught my eye first. :P

Comment: `input` returns a string. I have reviewed the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) again and tested on `Python3.3.0`, the value return is a string. @Alp

Answer (score 0):

The "else" block is only matched with the final "if prediction == number1 + 1". This means that if the correct number is guessed (or the number1 - 1 case) then it still also run the final else block.

You need to change the code to use "elif" for the intermediate conditionals:

```
if prediction == number1:
   pass # do the win
elif prediction == number1 - 1
   pass # do the win
elif prediction == number1 + 1
   pass  # do the win
else:
   pass # do the lose
```

Answer (score 0):

Your have three different if structures there. You almost certainly want

`if ...`

elif ...

elif ...

else